# Why did my Pixel 4a 5G on CalyxOS stop tracking mobile data usage?

Tags: custom-roms, mobile-data, data-monitoring, google-pixel

I am using CalyxOS on a Pixel 4a 5G. My phone did not track mobile data usage during the last three weeks.  In the screenshot below, we can see that it counted 8 MB.  But I used my entire monthly allotment of 5 GB between Sep 3 and Sep 26.  According to my math, that means it counted .15 percent of the actual data used.

[image: screenshot]

The results of a preliminary web inquiry tell me that there is no user option for disabling the data usage counting feature.  It is supposed to just work.  Does that sound correct?

Any thoughts about how this could happen?  Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe setting data warning or limit would help

Comment: Could also be a bug. Did you check in developer forum?

Comment: @beeshyams  In the screen shot we can see that the data warning was set to 2 Gb, but a warning was never issued even though I used the entire 5 Gb allotment of data.

Comment: Do you know or remember what has used them up to 5 GB?

Comment: @AndrewT.  The 5Gb data was consumed by normal media downloads.  Probably mostly videos.  It's a new phone and a new service plan.  I set the data warning and limit, then just relaxed.  I wasn't concerned about limiting my data consumption because I figured that I'd get a warning well in advance of using my entire monthly allotment of data.